# Rx.NET is there a combo operator that combines the goodness of Catch and Concat?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an observable that I needed to add a time-delay between the notifications on in case two notifications are too close to each other so I did this.

```
var niceAndSlowObservable = 
observable
  .Select(x => Observable.Return(x))
  .Delay(1000)
  .Concat();
```

Works awesome, no matter how fast items are emitted, I don't get no more than 1 notification per second.

Now, I have some processing/transformation going on that could result in an exception so I want to use catch.

```
niceAndSlowObservable
   .Select(x => TransformationThatCouldCauseException(x))
   .Catch<MyType, Exception>(x => 
               { 
                 HandleError(x);
                 return Observable.Empty<MyType>();
                });
```

The problem with the above is that, in case of an error, the entire stream stops, it does not just move on to the next one. Before Concat() call I do have "stream of streams", so technically the next one in line should become the fallback I am thinking,

Basically the something like the following code but without using try-catch blocks and Rx operators.

```
niceAndSlowObservable
   .Select(x => { 
          try { TransformationThatCouldCauseException(x); } catch () {return null;})
   .Where(x => x!= null);
```

how do I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for `Switch()`?

Comment: @stuartd What should it be replaced with? It needs to return a value

Comment: @fahadash When an observable terminates with an error (exception), then that observable stops by design. There is no "next one". Please [edit] your question on how you generate the items in the observable, how you want to proceed them and how/where/when an error occurs. Also show how exactly you want to handle the error/exception. If possible, add a marble diagram on how the items of the observable(s) should be generated.

Comment: @Progman Edited the question to add the transformation where an exception might occur. I know that OnError() is the death of the stream, but the upstream channel does have items coming, it is my transformed sequence that finished due to an error. I want the error to be ignored and the transformed sequence to move on to the next item from upstream channel.

Comment: @fahadash Depending on what you are trying to do, you can add a `try-catch` inside the `Select()` part, return `null` in case you get an exception and use `.Where(it => it != null)` afterwards.

Comment: @Progman  You are absolutely correct, I could turn my code into a procedural dump and add a `try-catch` block in the transformation. I am checking to see if there is an operator that can help me.

Comment: @fahadash You can embed the entries in individual single `IObservable` entries, where you can use the `Catch()` operator, check the example on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ORYx2j. But that is just doing `try-catch` with extra steps. When a `Select()` is failing with an exception that chain is terminating by design. You have to handle that exception "inside" if this chain shouldn't stop.

Comment: @Progman Thank you boss, really appreciate it. That is absolutely one way of doing it, I also found an approach very similar to yours. Please post yours as an answer.

Comment: @fahadash I didn't post it as an answer because that solution has way to much overhead for something which could be solved with a simple `try-catch`.

Comment: This is wrong: `var niceAndSlowObservable = observable.Select(x => Observable.Return(x)).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Concat();`. I think you mean this: `var niceAndSlowObservable = observable.Select(x => Observable.Return(x).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))).Concat();`.

Comment: @Progman - A simple `try`/`catch` won't solve this. What value do you return if you catch?

Comment: @Enigmativity What's wrong with the delay being on the outer wrapper? Just curious

Comment: @fahadash - It only delays the entire observable. I understood that you wanted to delay each value?

Comment: @Enigmativity A "marker" value like `null`, which can be filtered later with `Where()`, see my previous comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626276/rx-net-is-there-a-combo-operator-that-combines-the-goodness-of-catch-and-concat?noredirect=1#comment124851397_70626276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procmon and I both found an approach that are similar to each other. Here is what I was able to accomplish, probably not the best but works.

```
    var immortalObservable = 
    niceAndSlowObservable
       .Select(x => Observable.Start(() => TransformationThatCouldCauseException(x))
              .Catch<MyType, Exception>(ex => { LogError(ex)); return Observable.Empty<MyType>();}
       .Concat();
```

I  appreciate `Procmon's` input.

Comment: It's Progman :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to break the contract that an error ends an observable and you want to explicitly handle the exception then the way to do that is with `.Materialize()` and `.Dematerialize()`.

Try this:

```
IObservable<int> immortalObservable =
    niceAndSlowObservable
        .SelectMany(x =>
            Observable
                .Start(() => TransformationThatCouldCauseException(x))
                .Materialize()
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    if (x.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError)
                    {
                        HandleError(x.Exception);
                        return Notification.CreateOnCompleted<int>()
                    }
                    return x;
                })
                .Dematerialize());
```

This lets you manipulate the stream and change an error to a normal completed message. You get the chance to handle the actual exception.

Please note, as I needed to provide a type in `Notification.CreateOnCompleted<int>()` I've chosen `int`. You need to use the right type for your observable.